# video autoplay sometimes works sometimes not

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm using a video as a banner on my page. I want it to stop playing when someone is using mobile because of the data problems. Tried to use jquery to check the window size and stop if it's under 600px width. The problem is, sometimes the video start autoplaying on pc but if I refresh the page, it stops. I'm using js+jquery, tried to add right above the closing body tag and to the header aswell.
Somewhere I read that browsers prevent autoplaying on mobiles, but not sure if it's true. I'd be happy to hear some answers about it aswell.
This is my code:

```
<video class="video" id="video" loop="loop" muted="muted" preload="auto">
<source src="https://www.lacity.org/sites/g/files/wph1221/f/EchoPark_1920x800_loop.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Böngészője nem támogatja a  a HTML5 videót</video>
```

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  var screenWidth = $(window).width();
  if (screenWidth >= 600) {
    $('#video').attr('autoplay', 'autoplay');
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: depends on browser, most mobile browser need an event to trigger

Comment: try this  ("video").setAttribute('autoplay', true);

Comment: @JoshLin so I definitely need some js to stop playing on mobiles? Dhanuka: Same problem with that, sometimes works, sometimes not.

Comment: instead of `$('#video').attr('autoplay', 'autoplay')` try `$('#video').attr('autoplay', 'true')`

Comment: Got the same problem with it.

Comment: try just add autoplay to the html, as I said most mobile wont auto play at all, and pc shall not perfom different even you use jq, anyway I think only html may always peform always the same, you can have a try

Comment: It's working fine if I just add it to the html itself, but I'm a little bit worried about mobile devices. Are you sure, the old versions will show an image only?

Comment: not 100% sure, but pretty sure,  you can buy a cloud test to verify

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer. If someone know any 100% solution, I'm still up to listen to it.

Comment: also you can try add the attr after some timeout, or after load event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|OperaMini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
$('#video').attr('autoplay', 'autoplay');
}
```

this will be best approach to detect the users device, hope this may help you

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this code i hope help you.

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  var screenWidth = $(window).width();
  if (screenWidth >= 600) {
    $('#video').play();
  }
});
</script>
```